# Add two products to magento Shopping Cart simultaneously on click of add to cart button

Tags: session, magento, bundle, shopping-cart, recommendation-engine

I have been working on a LiftSuggest - an automatic Product Recommendations generator.

Now,I have introduced a bundling functionality which will bundle two products and assign discount.

**For example,**
On product page of A of the client's site,I(LiftSuggest) displays a bundle Saying "Buy A and B together and avail 10% off on net value". Now, when the user clicks on the add to cart button , I want both the products to be added simultaneously to cart. I had implemented the solution proposed on  [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/9797/) link, but I need the products to be added on click of add to cart button,without entering the quantity or providing the check box.Just imagine that you can see a box(  container) containing two products and on click of add to cart button-in that div container itself, both of them should be added to cart.I can make out that I need to store both the products in session, but I don't know exactly how to proceed.

Scripting language used:**PHP**

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are cart rules for various shopping carts. You can manipulate those rules through coding and achieve the desired output.